# Join the SAME tables from DIFFERENT databases

Tags: mysql, backup, join

I have an unusual situation where I have a bunch of backups of a mysql database and I am interested in selecting the distinct members of a given table from these backups (since some records might have been added or deleted). My thought is to use a cross database join, but I'm not sure if that really is what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so you want to comapre too almost dentical tables, then yes that is  a good way

Comment: Is your goal to get the distinct set of records from that table across each database? Is the table definition the same in each database (if you could add your table definition to your post that would be helpful).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE "out1" ... FROM db1.tbl ORDER BY ...;
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE "out2" ... FROM db2.tbl ORDER BY ...;
```

From shell:

```
diff out1 out2
```

the `ORDER BY` is to make sure the rows are in the same, predictable, order.  The `PRIMARY KEY` would be the optimal column(s) to specify.

If the tables were generated with *different* auto_increment values, then exclude that `id` from the `SELECT` list and use some other `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to get the data (not schema) differences, and the backups are already mounted as databases, then a simple `UNION` between all of the databases should be all you need to get the distinct set of rows, like this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Database1.YourTable

UNION

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Database2.YourTable

UNION

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Database3.YourTable
```

The [`UNION` clause](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx) automatically removes duplicate records.